# Postgres with no clients still chatty on network

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, network

This may be a non-issue but I was doing some network monitoring on my Mac and noticed that PostgreSQL (9.4.4) was still sending and receiving packets even when I'm not aware of any clients (localhost or remote) being connected to it.

Is there a way to see what's connected or is Postgres always chatty while it sits idle looking for a friend to talk to?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/856752/why-is-postgres-sending-network-traffic-on-osx

Comment: It's the UDP activity on localhost for stats collection.

Comment: So...it's normal?